# Cannot read property 'http' of undefined in test - Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, types

Attempting to get a fresh token for my test, but struggling to find the cause...

I'm not sure if this is the best way or whether I should be mocking it, but this is the way I want to do it for now...

The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'http' of undefined
        at getValidToken src/app/services/auth/auth.service.spec.ts:15:17)
        at Suite.<anonymous> src/app/services/auth/auth.service.spec.ts:31:22)
        at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
        at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:138:1)
        at Suite.<anonymous> node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:491:1)
        at Env.jasmineEnv.(anonymous function) [as fdescribe] node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:424:1)
        at Object../src/app/services/auth/auth.service.spec.ts src/app/services/auth/auth.service.spec.ts:8:1)
```

Comment: scope of 'this' has changed inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

`this` refears to the parent function so if you do

```
  function getValidToken() {
    return this.http.post(apiBaseUrl + '/auth', postTokenJson)
    .then(map(tok => {
      return tok;
    }));
  }
```

you will get an error since there's no `http` function inside `getValidToken`

the solution is to instanciate the parent 'this' inside a variable like this:

```
  var pThis=this;
  function getValidToken() {
    return pThis.http.post(apiBaseUrl + '/auth', postTokenJson)
    .then(map(tok => {
      return tok;
    }));
  }
```

Comment: If I do this, I get the error `Cannot read property 'post' of undefined` as the `post` now only expects 1 argument, the url...

Comment: Have you imported HTTPModule and HTTP appropriately ?

Comment: @physicsboy you may need to add a third argument which is the `postoptions` check [this](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request) and as @Vinayak said you need to check if the http module is well imported, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493298/typeerror-cannot-read-property-post-of-undefined) also may help

Comment: Yes I have imported correctly, and no, no postoptions are requried, it simply just wants an url which is not desirable